# Fail to create Spark SQLContext in Scala app

Tags: scala, apache-spark, sbt

I fail to create SQLContext . My code :

```
val sc = new SparkContext("local[*]", "myApp")
val sqlContext = new SQLContext(sc)
```

my sbt

```
import AssemblyKeys._
assemblySettings

name := "Ideas"

 version := "1.0"

scalaVersion := "2.10.5"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
 "org.scalatest" %% "scalatest" % "1.9.1" % "test",
 "junit" % "junit" % "4.12" % "test",
 "com.novocode" % "junit-interface" % "0.11" % "test->default",
 "org.mockito" % "mockito-core" % "1.9.5",
 "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "1.4.1",
 "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % "1.4.1",
 "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-hive" % "1.4.1",
 "org.apache.spark" % "spark-catalyst_2.10" % "1.4.1" 

)

 libraryDependencies += "org.apache.hadoop" % "hadoop-common" % "2.6.0"

resolvers += Resolver.mavenLocal

testOptions += Tests.Argument(TestFrameworks.JUnit, "-q", "-v")
EclipseKeys.withSource := true

parallelExecution in Test := false


enablePlugins(JavaAppPackaging)
```

the error stack

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.VerifyError: Bad type on operand stack
Exception Details:
 Location:
org/apache/spark/sql/SQLContext.optimizer$lzycompute()Lorg/apache/spark/sql/catalyst/optimizer/Optimizer; @20: putfield
 Reason:
Type 'org/apache/spark/sql/catalyst/optimizer/DefaultOptimizer$' (current frame, stack[1]) is not assignable to 'org/apache/spark/sql/catalyst/optimizer/Optimizer'
Current Frame:
bci: @20
flags: { }
locals: { 'org/apache/spark/sql/SQLContext', 'org/apache/spark/sql/SQLContext' }
stack: { 'org/apache/spark/sql/SQLContext', 'org/apache/spark/sql/catalyst/optimizer/DefaultOptimizer$' }
Bytecode:
0x0000000: 2a59 4cc2 2ab4 0091 1008 7e91 03a0 0016
0x0000010: 2ab2 00bc b500 be2a 2ab4 0091 1008 8091
0x0000020: b500 91b2 00a3 572b c32a b400 beb0 2bc3
0x0000030: bf                                     
  Exception Handler Table:
bci [4, 41] => handler: 46
 Stackmap Table:
append_frame(@35,Object[#2])
same_locals_1_stack_item_frame(@46,Object[#165])
```

Comment: Looks like a runtime problem. How are you trying to run your job ?

Comment: From Eclipse (Scala DE) I run main

Comment: Well... the approach of acquiring a SparkContext works when you are dealing with a SparkCuster as it provides support for getting acquired as a resource. But "local" spark does not behave as a resource that can be used by some Scala application using the SparkContext.

Comment: so what the solution for laptop ?

Comment: Just submit the as job to local spark using spark-submit or setup a local spark cluster. If you want an out of box spark cluster setup, you can download the hortonworks sandbox VM.

Comment: I had this same problem. Turns out I was using spark 1.6.3, and mvn dependency:tree showed that spark-sql_2.10 (version 1.6.3) was bringing in spark-catalyst_2.10 version 1.6.0. I put an explicit dependency in the pom.xml to bring in spark-catalyst_2.10 version 1.6.3. That solved it.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem for checking our cdh spark platform cluster's environment ,the reason is that our engineer let our devops upload a spark-sql.jar to the cdh spark lib jars folder【/app/opt/cloudera/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.12.0-1.cdh5.12.0.p0.29/lib/spark/appjars/spark-sql_2.10-1.6.0.jar】alone，actually it's noneed to do that for environment has already contain it，so， mv or delete  it just solve